# Emberjs 3.0 tests: how to select link by content

Tags: ember.js

The following is a test that apparently works in Ember.js 2.15, but seem not to work in version 3.0: 
*Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': 'a:contains('Contact')' is not a valid selector*.

```
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL, click } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';

module('Acceptance | list rentals', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);
    test('should show link to contact', async function(assert){
            await visit('/');
            await click("a:contains('Contact')");
            assert.equal(currentURL(),'/contact','should navigate to contact');
    });
});
```

How to do this in Ember.js 3.0?

I couldn't find it in the online Ember guides. The tutorials seem to refer thus to previous versions.

PS:The application's template file contains

```
 {{#link-to "contact"}}
    Contact
  {{/link-to}}
```

PS: The idea of using such a selector comes from the tutorial for Ember version...3.0! (See towards the end here https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/tutorial/routes-and-templates/)

EDIT: Emberjs 3.1 guide is already available and the tutorial examples finally match the new code:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/tutorial/model-hook/

Comment: I kinda think I remember hearing it was switched out for `includes`

Comment: ^ that was for enumerablehttps://emberjs.com/deprecations/v2.x/#toc_enumerable-contains - Well, it's saying that a:contains('Contact') is not a valid selector... that's like, a string... but - maybe it uses jQuery: api.jquery.com/contains-selector ? in which case... maybe jQuery is gone? I'm drinking a lot of theraflu...

Comment: I tried to make an example - but I failed: https://ember-twiddle.com/1b6873e66d36cba21ec4088989d5bce6?openFiles=tests.acceptance.my-acceptance-test.js%2C

Comment: Not in any way an answer... but I started using this the other day: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors - (beware the video uses a deprecated helper) . --- and what if you change the CTA to 'Call us' or something...

Comment: Something seems off. Not even finding all elements of a class with `find('.listing')` works: I get and undefined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add custom class name to {{#link-to}} and use that class name as a selector for click event

```
{{#link-to "contact" class="menu-contact"}}
   Contact
{{/link-to}}
```

And in my acceptance test i will call

```
 await click(".menu-contact");
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the belated answer. I also ran into more cases that didn't work (e.g find) and left it aside for a while. Finally the guides on version 3.1 already include the correct version of the new test syntax...Weird enough, is turns out to me more cumbersome...oh well.

Answer (score 2):

The new `find` helper from `@ember/test-helpers` uses the browser's native `document.querySelector` behind the scenes rather than jQuery. Unfortunately, since :contains is not a real CSS selector, it is not supported by any browser.

The older, global `find` helper is still available, if you use `moduleForAcceptance` instead of `setupApplicationTest`. I do not know if there are any plans to deprecate that in the future.

Personally I would recommend placing a class or a `data-test-` attribute on the element and search for it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this during an upgrade and think there's a way to get the jQuery pseudo-selectors back. It's a bit hacky, so think about whether you should re-write as the others advised.

1. import jQuery (assuming it's still in your app)
2. use `$(your-old-selector-string)[0]` to get a plain DOM element
3. pass the element to the test helper

I'm not confident that this is robust or future-proof, but it may be interesting during upgrades to get green tests before dealing with deprecations and whatnot.

Taking the original example and applying what I've done in a 3.8 app I'm updating:

```
// changed here
import $ from 'jquery'; // assuming @ember/jquery is in packages.json 

import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import { visit, currentURL, click } from '@ember/test-helpers';
import { setupApplicationTest } from 'ember-qunit';

module('Acceptance | list rentals', function(hooks) {
  setupApplicationTest(hooks);
    test('should show link to contact', async function(assert){
            await visit('/');
            // changed here
            await click($("a:contains('Contact')")[0]);
            assert.equal(currentURL(),'/contact','should navigate to contact');
    });
});
```